# CSV Export functionality is not working on wordpress Version 4.5.3

Tags: wordpress

We are using this type code in wordpress plugins creating time but is not working.

```
$data = array(
 '0' => array('Name'=> 'user1', 'Status' =>'complete', 'Priority'=>'Low', 'Salary'=>'001'),
 '1' => array('Name'=> 'user2', 'Status' =>'inprogress', 'Priority'=>'Low', 'Salary'=>'111'),
 '2' => array('Name'=> 'user3', 'Status' =>'hold', 'Priority'=>'Low', 'Salary'=>'333'),
 '3' => array('Name'=> 'user4', 'Status' =>'pending', 'Priority'=>'Low', 'Salary'=>'444'),
 '4' => array('Name'=> 'user5', 'Status' =>'pending', 'Priority'=>'Low', 'Salary'=>'777'),
 '5' => array('Name'=> 'user6', 'Status' =>'pending', 'Priority'=>'Low', 'Salary'=>'777')
);
```

this type array manage and then

```
$filename = "exportpin".time().".csv";
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
$header = array('name','Status', 'Priority','Salary');
header('Content-type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
fputcsv($fp, $header);

foreach($item_array as $datas) {
    fputcsv($fp, $datas);
}
exit;
```

this type error get

```
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at D:\xampp\htdocs\pinrotate\wp-includes\formatting.php:4596)
```

Comment: Can you provide code plugin file where to write this code

Comment: we have created custom plugins and created one function

Comment: do not use any echo or print and html before this code

Comment: yes we are using search html put

Comment: How can call your csv export function ?